# This is a ratio test question.

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

How do you use the ratio test to show whether

[image]

converges or diverges?

Using symbolab gave me something with "series root test", however it is not covered in my course. Would it be possible to show divergence/convergence without this? Thanks.

(The answer, according to the solutions, is converges.)

Comment: Let $a_n=\frac{n^{2n}}{3^n(2n)!}$. You must compute $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right|$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $a_{n}$ be the $n$-th term of our series. The ratio $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$ easily simplifies to 
$$\frac{(n+1)^{2n+2}}{3n^{2n}(2n+2)(2n+1)}.$$
Writing $(n+1)^{2n+2}$ as $(n+1)^2(n+1)^{2n}$ yields the further simplification
$$\frac{n+1}{6(2n+1)}\cdot \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{2n}.$$
The limit as $n\to\infty$ of $\frac{n+1}{6(2n+1)}$ is $\frac{1}{12}$, while  $\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{2n}$ has limit $e^2$.

It follows that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac{e^2}{12}\lt 1$, so by the Ratio Test our series converges.